# How I can move the shape left,right,up,down in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to move shape with button , but I am not getting it. This is my draw class

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent {


      public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fill3DRect(20, 20, 200, 200,true);
      }

    }
 class MyCanvas1 extends JComponent {


      public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(20, 20, 200, 200);
      }
    }
```

I done drawing successfully by below code -- >

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(check)
        {

            if(e.getSource()==btnNewButton)
            {
                MyCanvas can=new MyCanvas();
                me s=new me();
                can.setSize(400, 500);
                panel_3.add(can);
                panel_3.repaint();
                addComponent(can);
                s.can;
                choice=true;

            }
       }
      else
      {
       if(e.getSource()==btnNewButton)
            {
                panel_3.removeAll();
                MyCanvas1 can=new MyCanvas1();
                can.setSize(500, 500);
                panel_3.add(can);
                panel_3.repaint();
                addComponent(can);
            }
       }
```

Its working fine for me. Now I have another 4 button and I want to move the shape by click on button. I try few method but none of them working for me. Any suggestion how I can do it.Should I create any new action event or class.

Comment: First, learn how painting works in Swing, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

Comment: I am reading and still looking for solution

Comment: *"I try few method.."*  Show us what you tried in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: @JahidulIslam Fix your paint problems, then we talk solutions

Answer (score 2):

## First...

Learn how painting works in Swing, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

It is recommended that you override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and always make sure you call `super.paintComponent`

```
public class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fill3DRect(20, 20, 200, 200,true);
    }

}
```

## Second...

There are a number of ways you might achieve this, personally, I'd just make use of the [`Graphics2D` and `Shape`s APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/), but something tells me that's not be good enough for you, so...

Instead of trying to use component based shapes (and have to fight the layout manager), create an interface which describes a "drawable" element, something that can be painted...

```
public interface Drawable {
    public Rectangle getBounds();
    public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds);
    public Color getColor();
    public void setColor(Color color);
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d);
}
```

This describes something that can drawn, where and what color

Next, maintain a `List` of `Drawables`s and use the `paintComponent` method to paint them...

```
public class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    private List<Drawable> drawables;

    public MyCanvas() {
        drawables = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    public void add(Drawable drawable) {
        drawables.add(drawable);
        repaint();
    }

    public void remove(Drawable drawable) {
        drawables.remove(drawable);
        repaint();
    }

    public int getDrawableCount() {
        return drawables.size();
    }

    public Drawable getDrawableAt(int index) {
        return drawables.get(index);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        for (Drawable d : drawables) {
            d.draw(g2d);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Now you have something that be painted and something that can paint them...

## Third...

Make something to draw.  I'd start with an abstract `Drawable` which covers all the common stuff to make life easier...

```
public abstract class AbstractDrawable {
    private Rectangle bounds;
    private Color color

    public AbstractDrawable(Rectangle bounds, Color color) {
        setBounds(bounds);
        setColor(color);
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }
    public void setBounds(Dimension bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d);
}
```

The you can go nuts...

```
public class DrawableRectangle {

    public AbstractDrawable(Rectangle bounds, Color color) {
        super(bounds, color);
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(getColor());
        g2d.fill(getBounds());
    }
}
```

And/or...

```
public class Drawable3DRectangle {

    public AbstractDrawable(Rectangle bounds, Color color) {
        super(bounds, color);
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(getColor());
        Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
        g2d.fill3DRect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
    }
}
```

## Fourthly...

Put it all together...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawableShapes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawableShapes();
    }

    public DrawableShapes() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private MyCanvas canvas;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            canvas = new MyCanvas();
            add(canvas);

            canvas.add(new Drawable3DRectangle(new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 100), Color.RED));
            canvas.add(new DrawableRectangle(new Rectangle(20, 140, 100, 100), Color.RED));

        }

    }

}
```

Okay, so this paint two drawables, but how to move them??

Basically, you grab a reference to the `Drawable` you want to move, something like...

```
Drawable drawable = canvas.getDrawableAt(0);
```

Then you modify it's location...

```
drawable.getBounds().x += 5;
drawable.getBounds().y += 5;
```

Then you repaint the `MyCanvas` instance...

```
canvas.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick code for you just to get the idea from
You can do so by using Component setLocation(int x, int y); For the getting the current x and y positions may use the JComponent getX() and getY() methods.

For example comp.setLocation(comp.getX(), comp.getY());

```
public class Move extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JComponent b = new JButton("Move me");
    JButton a = new JButton("Move that");
    Random rd = new Random();

    public Move() throws HeadlessException {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(a);
        add(b);
        a.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Move();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        int r = rd.nextInt(400);
        b.setLocation(b.getX(), r);
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll be lucky if the `a` and `b` don't paint over what the frame's `paint` method paints...

Comment: *"For example comp.setLocation(comp.getX(), comp.getY());"* - Not while there is a layout manager involved, the moment that the container is revalidated, the components positions and sizes will be reset to whatever the layout manager wants to use and I wouldn't suggest using a `null` layout for this, as it's inappropriate for what's really needs to be done will only attract the wrath of senior Swing posters.